# Security implications of injection in api http request from frontend?

Tags: javascript, injection

In my frontend I have something like this:

```
article = httpLibrary.get('api.mysite.com/articles/' + articleId);
```

Where articleId is taken from a URL query parameter (it's injectable).

Is this exploitable in any way?

I was thinking of trying to inject a newline and see if I can make it perform two requests. That way I would be able to return any data I want if the second, malicious, request returns first. However, injecting CRLF and NULL bytes did nothing.

Comment: If this is a problem depends on the details of how `httpLibrary.get` is implemented on the client side and how the server reacts to such a request (i.e. application logic server side). Nothing of this is known which makes the question too broad.

Comment: *Probably* not vulnerable, but it´s good practice to validate input anyway. If `articleId` should be all numbers, make sure it is all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other committers says: it is dependent on the implementation of the `httpLibrary.get`.

You can simplify the httpLibrary.get to a function, it can do anything from just NOP to run a complete job. Before the shellshock the programmers would not notice that environment variable could cause the RCE.

You can follow the [OWASP Top 10 - A1 Injection](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf): always using the safe API, white-list server-side input validation, escape  special characters and others.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you could do with an injection; `article` would be of your choice, but this needn't be helpful.

Nonetheless, if `httpLibrary.get` does take a URL string, you can easily inject this and return arbitrary data for `article`:

Setting `articleId` to `@yourdomain.tld/yourpath` should make everything in front of it a user name for http basic auth.

Comment: If I could return arbitrary data, then that would allow for XSS.

That's true that HTTP basic auth works, but unfortunately, if you try this:
`https://api.mysite.com:test@malicious.site.com`
Then the request really will be made to malicious.site.com.
However,if you try this:
`https://api.mysite.com/articles/1:test@malicious.site.com`
Then the request is instead made to api.mysite.com.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the implementation. Was worth a shot, tho